# Can't find the dist file

Tags: node.js, npm

This is a noob question but when I run `npm run build` on a vue app I am working on, I get the following message:
`rimraf dist; node build/build.js`
I don't understand what that means, but worse I don't see a dist file created anywhere (which I need to run locally). 
Where is it? 
What does the output mean?

Comment: rimraf dist means `rm -rf  dist` and run  `node build/build.js`

Answer (score 0):

turns out a ";" won't work on windows, I needed to build directly through node not using a preset npm command.